# How do I recover an Entity Framework 4 EDMX file when Visual Studio 2010 will not open it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have been following the examples from Chapter 2 in an early access edition of [Entity Framework 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/) whereby one creates a database schema, generates an entity model from the database schema, and then performs some entity customizations with regards to object inheritance, adding complex properties, etc. Everything was great until I closed and then restarted Visual Studio 2010 SP1. After restarting, I can no longer open the EDMX file with the designer. I get a dialog box stating "Cannot load 'C:\Projects\Test\Test.MyModel\Model.edmx': An item with the same key has already been added.". There is no further information in the Output window.

1. How might one might recover the file?
2. How might one debug the model loading process to find a little more information on what "item" is attempting to load or even what type of "item" it is?

Comment: Can you at least use 'Open with' and open it as XML? If you open it as XML is there any marked section (red underlined as error). If you can't openned the file at all it will be most probably error in project file.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, I had seen the xml but hadn't thought of scrolling looking for squiggly lines. Unfortunately, no squiggly lines.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but this might be worth a shot - http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/10/LINQ-to-SQL-DBML-fails-to-build-or-open

Comment: Thanks for the link, @MattDavey. It was worth a shot. Unfortunately, it's localized to this specific EF model due to steps followed with the EF designer. Still haven't taken the time to come back to this. Thinking of parsing the xml w/ linq-to-xml to find duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It's an XML file so you can open it up in text mode and see what the problem is.  Sounds like there could be items with duplicate names somehow.

Comment: Thanks DamienG, I had seen the XML but I was hoping that there was a more directed way to hone in on the problem. This simple model has ~1000 lines of xml.